# zend framework include another class in my action controller

Tags: zend-framework, class, autoload

I am newbie in zend framework ,

a simple question :

in my IndexController file , I want to instance new class.

I put the file of class declaration under ***/library***

and of course its in the include path (index.php)

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path()
)));
```

I get an error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Profile' not found in ....
```

what is the way to auto load this class ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to put this class in models ...not in library
and use

```
set_include_path('./application/models'); in index.php
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you could add namespaces to the autoloader.

So if your class was named `My_Profile`, stored in a the file `library/My/Profile.php`, you could add the following to your `application/config/application.ini`:

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "My_"
```

or in your `Bootstrap` class's `_initAutoload()` method:

```
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('My_');
```

See [Zend Framework: Autoloading a Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151773/zend-framework-autoloading-a-class-library)