# Zend framework 2 skeleton import class from outside

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

So I have a setup of the Zend Framework 2 skeleton, and I want to add a class that I have made, file.class.php , and I want to use it in an action controller.

1. Where should this file go?
2. Can I set an autoload? I don't want to use require_once in my action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to respect the PSR-0 standards:

You can add your file to /module/Application/src/Application/Service/Classname.php
Add the correct namespace and classname to your file:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Service;

class Classname
{
}
```

You can then use it in your controller as:

```
$obj = new Application\Service\Classname;
```

There are even better ways to add code to ZF2, check out [this good introduction to the ServiceManager](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/zend-framework-2-cheat-sheet-service-manager/).

Answer (score 0):

in your Bootstrap add the following to the _initAutoload():

```
 Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('name');
```

[Zend Framework: Autoloading a Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151773/zend-framework-autoloading-a-class-library)

Comment: That's for ZF 1 not for ZF2 which I need